# PL/SQL Extract Column Names and use in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

ADB Table

[image: ADB Table]

Todays Date

[image: Todays Date]

I have a ADB table. I want to extract the Column name base on system date

I'm currently trying the following which is not working.

```
SELECT (
        SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(TODAY, 'MON') || '_' || TO_CHAR(TODAY, 'D') AS TODAY
        FROM STTM_DATES
        )
FROM adb
```

I'm trying this script but no result set.

```
SQLSTMT VARCHAR2(2000); 
SQLSTMT := 'SELECT' || ' ' || (SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(TODAY,'MON') || '_' || TO_CHAR(TODAY,'D')AS TODAY FROM STTM_DATES)||' ' || 'FROM ADB'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTMT;
```

Comment: Your table design looks sub optimal to me.  Instead of storing each day in separate column, which won't scale, and will lead to the need for hacks, store all timestamps in a single column.  Then, you can easily use a `WHERE` clause to search for the current day in that single column.

Comment: I will be using this script to update the adb per day that's why I want to get the column..content ADB table is CUST_AC_NO
JAN_2
JAN_3
JAN_4
JAN_5
JAN_6
JAN_7....Dec 31

Comment: My words have fallen on deaf ears, because I think you need to fix your table design.  _Don't_ store one day in a separate column, use a single column for all days.

Comment: I'm trying this script but no result set.    SQLSTMT VARCHAR2(2000);
SQLSTMT := 'SELECT' || ' ' || (SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(TODAY,'MON') || '_' || TO_CHAR(TODAY,'D')AS TODAY FROM STTM_DATES)||' ' || 'FROM ADB';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTMT;

Comment: An important note : Please don't post images for sample data and result set. Just copy paste in plain text. Your table design looks awful and you need to fix it. The solution you are looking for could actually make it messier if implemented.

Comment: Okay thanks @KaushikNayak

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting just a single row, you need a target to store that result (and an INTO expression), eg

```
SQL> create table t ( a1 int, a2 int, a3 int );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (1,2,3);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    col_name varchar2(30);
  3    result int;
  4  begin
  5    col_name := 'a1';
  6    execute immediate 'select '||col_name||' from t' into result;
  7    dbms_output.put_line(result);
  8
  9    col_name := 'a2';
 10    execute immediate 'select '||col_name||' from t' into result;
 11    dbms_output.put_line(result);
 12  end;
 13  /
1
2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you are receiving a set of rows, you would need to cycle through a cursor.

```
SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (4,5,6);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    col_name varchar2(30) := 'a3';
  3    result int;
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for 'select '||col_name||' from t';
  7    loop
  8      fetch rc into result;
  9      exit when rc%notfound;
 10      dbms_output.put_line(result);
 11    end loop;
 12    close rc;
 13  end;
 14  /
3
6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>
```

But neither of these fix the concerns others have expressed about the potential design issues here.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTDET(CUSTACNO NUMBER, DT DATE, VAL NUMBER);
INSERT INTO CUSTDET VALUES(1, SYSDATE-2, 10);
INSERT INTO CUSTDET VALUES(1, SYSDATE-1, 20);
INSERT INTO CUSTDET VALUES(1, SYSDATE, 30);
INSERT INTO CUSTDET VALUES(2, SYSDATE-2, 40);
INSERT INTO CUSTDET VALUES(3, SYSDATE-1, 10);
INSERT INTO CUSTDET VALUES(3, SYSDATE, 20);
COMMIT;
```

You don't need a dynamic sql for this.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'MON')||'_'||TO_CHAR(dt,'D') AS today FROM custdet;
```

Output:

```
TODAY
MAR_1
MAR_2
MAR_3
MAR_1
MAR_2
MAR_3
```

If you want to use a dynamic sql you need to receive the output in a variable or table variable to display it separately.

```
DECLARE
    SQLSTMT VARCHAR2(2000); 
    TYPE MYTABTYP IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
    MYTABVAR MYTABTYP := MYTABTYP();
BEGIN
    SQLSTMT := q'[SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'MON')||'_'||TO_CHAR(dt,'D') AS today FROM custdet]';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTMT BULK COLLECT INTO MYTABVAR;
    FOR idx IN MYTABVAR.FIRST..MYTABVAR.LAST
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MYTABVAR(idx));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
MAR_1
MAR_2
MAR_3
MAR_1
MAR_2
MAR_3
```